# Python: uuid.uuid1() uniqueness test failure on wheezy/virtualbox

Tags: python, debian, virtual-machine, virtualbox, uuid

Python's test case to test uniqueness of uuid.uuid1() in test_uuid.py is failing on Debian Wheezy on Virtualbox. However, when I change it to use uuid.uuid4(), it's successful always. I don't have wheezy installed on a bare machine to test.

I faced this problem while installing Python 2.7.6 on my virtualbox. This is blocking a successful installation.

The failure is that uuid1 is able to create around 995-998 unique uuids out of 1000 iterations most of the time.

Can anyone throw some light on this failure. I have created a small test file as given below.

```
import uuid
def test_uuid():
    uuids = {}
    for u in [uuid.uuid1() for i in range(1000)]:
        uuids[u] = 1

    print i+1, len(uuids.keys())
    if i+1 != len(uuids.keys()): print 'FAIL'
    else: print 'SUCCESS'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_uuid()
```

Note that I have posted this on debian forum (http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=109067), reposting it here for a wider audience and probably a quicker answer.

Answer (score 1):

A Type 1 UUID consists of the following (from the [Cassandra wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/TimeBaseUUIDNotes)):

> - A timestamp consisting of a count of 100-nanosecond intervals since 00:00:00.00, 15 October 1582 (the date of Gregorian reform to the Christian calendar).
> - A version (which should have a value of 1).
> - A variant (which should have a value of 2).
> - A sequence number, which can be a counter or a pseudo-random number.
> - A "node" which will be the machines MAC address (which should make the UUID unique across machines).

So, assuming you are generating UUIDs quickly (i.e., that you have the same timestamp for a large number of the `uuid.uuid1` calls - not necessarily the whole thousand) the only thing that varies between the generation of one uuid to the next is the sequence number. This is a random number, 14 bits in length (from the [uuid.uuid1 docs](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/pep-0384/Lib/uuid.py)):

> If 'clock_seq' is given, it is used as the sequence number;
>       otherwise a random 14-bit sequence number is chosen.

This gives you 16384 possibilities. You are choosing (anything up to) 1000 random numbers from this pool of possibilities and expecting to get 1000 unique numbers. It's possible, but highly unlikely due to the [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). Uniqueness is neither guaranteed or likely on a long enough run.

Comment: Good explanation. However, note that this failure is only on virtual machines and not on native desktop. And the failure rate on virtual machine is 8 out of 10, which is very high at ~80%.

Comment: Exact timing can be difficult on virtual machines - check out the note on Tick Counting in [this VMWare document on timekeeping](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/Timekeeping-In-VirtualMachines.pdf). Could you check the clocktime before and after the for loop in your code and compare with the results running on local desktop?

Comment: I did the testing with time, as you had mentioned. I notice that on virtualbox, it takes more time which is fine. Here is what I find: on virtualbox: time diff between start and stop is ~0.0447521 and on desktop: it is 0.033798 secs.

Comment: I tested this on a digitalocean droplet which is on KVM and there are absolutely no failures in 20 runs! Therefore, this is probably something to do with virtualbox?

Comment: Cool, that sounds like it's caused by timing on virtualbox all right. The other thing you could do is save the timeuuids and check what the timestamp component is - the fact that it's failing on 8/10 suggests you could be close to a threshold (you're potentially entering into Heisenberg territory now though). Bottom line though, if you're picking random uuids you are always running the risk of coming up with two non-unique uuids if you pick twice with the same timestamp.